# Mutithreading in Win32

Tags: multithreading, winapi

is there any good book/video/web tutorials for multithreading in win32? I only found `Addison-Wesley - Multithreading Applications in Win32 (1996)` book and might going to order it soon.

Comment: msdn has a lot of info, but it is spread among different articles

Comment: With which programming language?  e.g. Are you going to use MSVC++?

Comment: Don't order a book that old. There are plenty of good tutorials on the net. Try Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can easily look up a lot of reference material and [examples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa270957%28v=VS.60%29.aspx) in addition to a plethora of books on the subject:

- [Win32 Multithreaded Programming](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565922969) By Aaron Cohen, Mike Woodring
- [Multithreading Applications in Win32: The Complete Guide to Threads](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201442345) by Jim Beveridge (he has published a few of these)
- [Concurrent Programming on Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X) By Joe Duffy (already mentioned in the other answer)

This question might have been partially answered previously also - [have a look here - "Recommended Multithreading Book"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156922/recommended-multithreading-book) (but not for Windows specifically)

Answer (score 0):

Joe Duffy's "[Concurrent Programming on Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X)" is good - it covers both native code and managed code though, so if you're not interested in managed code (and don't expect to be) then you'll find half of it irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best source for Win32 programming is Jeffrey Richter's "[Windows via C/C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735624240)"

Answer (score 0):

Try [this tutorial](http://www.computersciencelab.com/MultithreadingTut1.htm) if you're using C++.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting a book, I would start with:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/concurrency/default.aspx

There is a Learn Parallelism section that includes videos, etc.  Covers both native (i.e. Win32) and managed.

Answer (score 0):

These will definitely benefit you:

- [MT Guide 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43994/The-Practical-Guide-to-Multithreading-Part-1)
- [MT Guide 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65158/The-Practical-Guide-to-Multithreading-Part-2)